# What is the name of this sorting algorithm in c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting

```
 public static int[] Sort(int[] ints)
        {
            var dictionary = new IndexedDictionary<int, int>();

            foreach (var i in ints)
            {
                dictionary.Add(i, i);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i <= ints.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                var indexValue = dictionary[i].Key;

                dictionary[indexValue - 1].Value = indexValue;
            }

            return dictionary.Values();
        }
```

Is it a bucket sort? I've seen a few bucket sorts and they look more complicated than this. Also please ignore the IndexedDictionary class - its a custom class to allow for getting values by index.

Edit: CompuChip - if you want to see the IndexedDictionary:

```
 public class IndexedDictionary<T, TY>
    {
       public class DicObject<T, Y>
        {
            public T Key { get; set; }
            public Y Value { get; set; }
        }

       private HashSet<DicObject<T, TY>> list = new HashSet<DicObject<T, TY>>();

        public void Add(T o, TY u)
        {
            list.Add(new DicObject<T, TY>{Key = o, Value = u});
        }

        public DicObject<T, TY> this[int i] {
             get{return list.ElementAt(i);}
        }

        public T[] Keys()
        {
            return list.Select(x => x.Key).ToArray();
        }

        public TY[] Values()
        {
            return list.Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Its not the crux at all.

Comment: Sorting on what property is that?

Comment: I'm not sure how we can ignore the `IndexedDictionary` as it seems to be the crux of your algorithm, but assuming it works like a standard dictionary I would think this is basically an insert sort - you put all your values into a dictionary which inserts it in the right place to keep its keys sorted.

Comment: This seems to add new values to the dictionary, are you sure this is *just* a *sorting* implementation?

Comment: You call this class IndexedDictionary? Then we can call every `List<T`> Dictionary and every `IEnumerable<T>` Indexed.

Comment: You mean `IndexedDictionary<T, U>` is really just a `List<KeyValuePair<K, V>>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a form of [pigeon hole sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_sort), but it's limited to only being capable of sorting collections with unique values ranging from 1 and up without gaps. (If you for example try to sort the array `{4,3,2}` it will crash.)

So, for any collection that it works for, it does the same thing as:

```
public static int[] Sort(int[] ints) {
  return Enumerable.Range(1, ints.Length).ToArray();
}
```

The `IndexedDictionary` is only a complicated and slow way to iterate through the items in an arbitrary order and put each value in place according to the same arbitrary order so that they end up being sorted. You can do the same thing much simpler and faster with a regular array:

```
public static int[] Sort(int[] ints) {
  int[] result = new int[ints.Length];
  foreach (int value in ints) {
    result[value - 1] = value;
  }
  return result;
}
```

For an implementation that works with collections that doesn't have to have a lowest value of 1 and be continuous, you would create an array that spans from the lowest to the highest value and put the values in it, then collect them in order:

```
public static int[] Sort(int[] ints) {
  int min = ints.Min();
  int max = ints.Max();
  int?[] pigeonHoles = new int?[max - min + 1];
  foreach (int value in ints) {
    pigeonHoles[value - min] = value;
  }
  int[] result = new int[ints.Length];
  int index = 0;
  foreach (int? value in pigeonHoles) {
    if (value.HasValue) {
      result[index++] = value.Value;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how we can ignore the `IndexedDictionary` as it seems to be the crux of your algorithm, but assuming it works like a standard dictionary I would think this is basically an insert sort - you put all your values into a dictionary which inserts it in the right place to keep its keys sorted and in the end you just extract all the values which are in the proper order by then. However, all the hard work is invisible because it is  inside the `Dictionary` class.

A similar solution in terms of standard classes would be something like

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Sort(int[] ints)
{
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, bool>();

    foreach (var i in ints)
    {
        dictionary.Add(i, false);
    }

    return dictionary.Keys;
}
```

(although this does not deal with numbers occurring more than once).